# How to check collisions between a mask and rect. in pygame?

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

I have created a pygame mask around the main sprite. My game consists of tiles with collisions rects. set up around them.

How can I check if the mask on my main sprite collides with a rect. of one of my tiles in my world without having to create more masks (as that is inefficient)? I know there are 'collide rect' and 'collide mask' functions in pygame. Is a collision function for a mask and a rect?

Answer (score 1):

> Is a collision function for a mask and a rect?

No, but you could write one yourself and use it as callback for the group collide functions:

```
def collide_mask_rect(left, right):
    xoffset = right.rect[0] - left.rect[0]
    yoffset = right.rect[1] - left.rect[1]
    try:
        leftmask = left.mask
    except AttributeError:
        leftmask = pygame.mask.Mask(left.size, True)
    try:
        rightmask = right.mask
    except AttributeError:
        rightmask = pygame.mask.Mask(right.size, True)
    return leftmask.overlap(rightmask, (xoffset, yoffset))
```

The real perfomance issue with masks is creating them at runtime from a surface (like [`collide_mask`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.collide_mask) does with [`from_surface`](https://github.com/pygame/pygame/blob/21b158bb679eadb807984fbbe647782ed32417f5/src_py/sprite.py#L1475), but creating filled masks shouldn't be that bad.

But if performance becomes an issue, consider either caching the masks, assigning them to the sprites or create them in the sprites in advance.